# How to pass an xml documents as a input to android xml pullparser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

In my application the user can download an XML file witch is stored on the internal memory. Is there a way to pass this file given its absolute path to a XMLPullParser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file saved internally you don't need absolute path you just need the file name:

```
final String xmlFile="fileName";
 FileInputStream fis = null;
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            char[] inputBuffer = null;
            String data = null;
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                fis = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(xmlFile);
                isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                inputBuffer = new char[fis.available()];
                isr.read(inputBuffer);
                data = new String(inputBuffer);
                isr.close();
                fis.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
            try {
                factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = null;
            try {
                xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            try{
                xpp.setInput( new StringReader (data) );
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                }
             int eventType = 0;
             try{
                 eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                }
             while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                 if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                     System.out.println("Start document");
                 }else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                     System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
                 }else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                     System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
                 }else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                     items.add(xpp.getText());
                 }
                 try{
                     eventType = xpp.next();
                }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
            String item1=contact.get(0);
        String item2=contact.get(1);
        String item3 = contact.get(2);
        String item4=contact.get(3);
```